# Accessing Property Values of a Protocol?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, macos, properties

Hey guys, I have a protocol which defines a number of ObjC-2.0 properties, like so:

```
@protocol Repeatable <NSCoding>
@required
@property (nonatomic, retain) Date *startDate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Date *endDate;
@end
```

I have another class that implements the protocol:

```
@interface AbstractRepeatable : NSObject <Repeatable>
```

And finally, in AbstractRepeatable, I am implementing a method defined by the protocol:

```
- (BOOL)isEqualToRepeatable:(Repeatable *)r {
    if (r.startDate != startDate) // Compiler error here
        return NO;
    return YES;
}
```

Bits and pieces have been excluded for example-sake, but when compiling, I receive the familiar "request for member 'startDate' in something not a structure or union" on the line noted above. The AbstractRepeatable obviously includes the Repeatable header, otherwise the protocol would not be visible, so I don't know which part I'm missing.

Comment: This answer might clear some things up for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/844678/how-to-handle-objective-c-protocols-that-contain-properties/844785#844785

Comment: I'm synthesizing the property in AbstractRepeatable, I can't figure out why the prop isn't recognized.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your `isEqualToRepeatable:` method you are treating Repeatable as a class, not a protocol.  Try using the following.  Everything should work fine after that.  I tested it.  (Fingers crossed that I won't look stupid.)

```
- (BOOL)isEqualToRepeatable:(id<Repeatable>)r {
    if (r.startDate != startDate) // Compiler error here
        return NO;
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I'd be surprised that entirely fixes the issue.  There is a serious bug in the existing compilers with @property() in protocols.

Answer (score 1):

That should work and do what you expect.  But it doesn't because the compiler is broken.

Sorry about that.

As a workaround, you'll need to declare the methods in your protocol:

```
@protocol Repeatable <NSCoding>
@required
@property (nonatomic, retain) Date *startDate;
- (Date *) startDate;
- (void) setStartDate: (Date *) aDate;

@property (nonatomic, retain) Date *endDate;
- (Date *) endDate;
- (void) setEndDate: (Date *) aDate;
@end
```

Skipping the @property, if you want.  Once the compiler is fixed, the above still won't generate any warnings.

(Yes, you still can @synthesize the methods.  I believe that @synthesize will work in this case.  If it doesn't -- which it might not -- then you'll need to redeclare the properties in the class -- potentially in a class extension -- until the compiler is fixed.  If this second issue proves to be the case, please file a bug via http://bugreport.apple.com/)

Comment: I believe the compiler is synthesizing the getters/setters. See the chosen answer for a good explanation.

Comment: The compiler is synthesizing the getter/setters.  That isn't the problem.  The problem is that the compiler does not see @property() in class declarations as indicating that methods are required correctly.  In some cases, it'll lead to incorrect code gen.

Answer (score 0):

`@property ... startDate` only declares two methods `-startDate` and `-setStartDate:`.

You have to actually implement them. In a protocol, this cannot be done with instance variables.

Comment: Defining the properties in the protocol just ensures that the subclasses (or implementers, more specifically) synthesize the properties, and that you can pass in any Repeatable to a method, and have code that acts on those properties, assuming they exist in the actual object, which is an implementation of that protocol.

Comment: I should clarify - Defining the properties in the protocol does not synthesize the variables. Any implementation of the protocol *must* synthesize (or provide dynamic accessor methods) to ensure that the property is "maintained."

Comment: This is a good point. Have you tried to replace (r.startDate != startDate) by (r.startDate != [self startDate]) ?

Comment: The compiler error was on the r.startDate 'getter', not the startDate instance var. Answer chosen above. :)

Comment: In XCode 4.4, we got the following change: "Objective-C @properties are synthesized by default when not explicitly implemented."