# Objective-C , protocol as a property inside another protocol

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a simple protocol called as **OnSuggestionTextChanged**

```
@protocol OnSuggestionTextChanged <NSObject>
-(void)onTextChanged:(NSString*)newText;
@end
```

And I have another protocol called as **TextEditable** which has this protocol as a property

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "OnSuggestionTextChanged.h"

@protocol TextEditable <NSObject>

@required
-(void)setTextString:(NSString*)text;
-(NSString*)textString;
-(void)notifySuggestionButtonPressed;
-(NSInteger)cursorPosition;

@property(nonatomic,weak)id<OnSuggestionTextChanged> onSuggestionTextChange;

@end
```

But in my custom `UITextView` which conforms to the protocol `TextEditable`.

When I try to access the property `OnSuggestionTextChanged` 
I get a:

> **unrecognized selector for [CustomTextView onSuggestionTextChanged]** 
>   (**not** for onTextChanged)

which is really weird because Xcode doesn't throw a compiler error but a runtime error.

Can you please tell me if what I am trying to do is really possible. If so, why am I getting unrecognized selector?

Just in case you guys don't believe me.

[image]

Comment: If a protocol includes a `@property`, that does *NOT* mean the property is now part of all implementing classes. Rather, it's *your* responsibility in classes adhering to the protocol (like your `UITextView` subclass) to ensure that the property exists. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/844785/88111 Also, as @rmaddy mentions below, adding `@synthesize` to your subclass should generate the getters/setters for you.

Comment: In your class that conforms to the `TextEditable` protocol, try adding `@synthesize onSuggestionTextChange;`.

Comment: Using properties in protocol is bad practise. You should rethink your protocol.

Comment: Btw. I have checked. Xcode throws compiler warning: `Auto property synthesis will not synthesize property declared in a protocol`.

Comment: you need to implement the _setter_ and _getter_ for that property e.g. using the `@synthesize`, if the default ones are good enough for you. if not, you can still implement own ones.

Comment: @Cy-4AH : Can you justify why using a property in the protocol is a bad practice ?

Comment: @TapanThaker, protocols should do some stuff with data, not provide data.

Comment: My problem is this: I want a Editable so that I can abstract myself from UITextView or UITextField, and I want my Editable to receive callbacks when text has been changed. So it seemed reasonable to have a delegate property to send callbacks

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here :

> properties defined in protocols are not synthesized automatically, instead you need to synthesize them in the class that conforms to the protocol.

Also, I didn't receive a compile time error, but there is a warning as @Cy-4AH stated that says :

> Auto property synthesis will not synthesize property declared in a protocol

Thank you guys for the comments above.